# React Native - How to make two devices communicate between each other when connected to the same network?

Tags: node.js, react-native, mobile, p2p, wifip2p

I'm working on a personal project in React Native and part of it involves two devices, regardless of whether they're Android or iOS and both using this app, sending each other some data in a JSON format. To give some context, three devices (A, B and C) are connected to the same wifi network and once device A created a group, devices B and C should be able to find device A through a unique id and then send data to it. Device A, upon receiving data, will do some stuff and send a status code back.

I couldn't find questions about this related to react native, but more about Android and WifiP2P. I also found an npm packages ([p2p](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p2p)), but being new to React Native, I'm not sure if you can use them or if they only apply to browser-related code.

Can you guys help me finding libraries to use to accomplish this?

Edit: I also found [this](https://github.com/alexkendall/react-native-bluetooth-cross-platform/blob/master/sdk.md) package, but it looks like you have to invite a device to be part of a channel, rather than ask to join. Can anyone confirm if that library could work for my purposes and if there's a workaround for the issue I just described?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `react-native-wifi-p2p`

`react-native-wifi-p2p` is a library that provides `WiFi` Direct (peer-to-peer) services to a `react native` system.

**Important**: currently only `Android` support realized. If you want to provide iOS support, then you should to note to [react-native-multipeer](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-multipeer) repository.

Comment: Would an iOS device be able to communicate with an Android device if I use those two different libraries?

Comment: To communicate with iOS, use a react-native-multipeer.

Comment: My question is whether Android and iOS would still be able to communicate with each other even if the libraries are different

Comment: It is not known unless the module is analyzed inside. It may be possible if the communication types are the same. However, it is not desirable to communicate in different modules.

Comment: What do you mean with your last statement?

Comment: When trying to communicate on a device,we recommend doing it in the same module.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you mean, would you mind giving a more eli5 explanation? I'm new to react native, so I don't think I know enough to understand your explanation yet

Comment: this is package  not showing any devices .do you know any other package ?